# When to use CTEs to encapsulate sub-results, and when to let the RDBMS worry about massive joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, theory

This is a SQL theory question. I can provide an example, but I don't think it's needed to make my point. Anyone experienced with SQL will immediately know what I'm talking about.

Usually we use joins to minimize the number of records due to matching the left and right rows. However, under certain conditions, joining tables cause a multiplication of results where the result is all permutations of the left and right records.

I have a database which has 3 or 4 such joins. This turns what would be a few records into a multitude. My concern is that the tables will be large in production, so the number of these joined rows will be immense. Further, heavy math is performed on each row, and the idea of performing math on duplicate rows is enough to make anyone shudder.

I have two questions. The first is, is this something I should care about, or will SQL Server intelligently realize these rows are all duplicates and optimize all processing accordingly?

The second is, is there any advantage to grouping each part of the query so as to get only the distinct values going into the next part of the query, using something like:

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT... [or GROUP BY]

),
t2 AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT...

),
t3 AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT...

)
SELECT...
```

I have often seen the use of DISTINCT applied to subqueries. There is obviously a reason for doing this. However, I'm talking about something a little different and perhaps more subtle and tricky.

Comment: SQL Server will likely push the compute scalar operator down to operate on the minimum number of rows. Check the execution plan. I wouldn't put logically unnecessary `distinct` statements in as it may cause unnecessary sorts.

Comment: So the hundreds of thousands of rows that boil down to in fact only a few hundred are likely "virtual"?  However, saying "SELECT * FROM T, T, T, T, T, T" where T has 10 rows WILL create 1 million rows. The question is, will these only be created if they are asked for? Why does this suddenly feel like the question, "If a tree falls in the woods, and no one is there to hear it, does it still make a noise?" lol

Comment: i would question your database design, or query design, if you have to bake in the distinct from the get-go.

Comment: @DForck42 I half agree. Of course, a design could be inefficient and cause inefficient processing. I spent a few hours and carefully modified the queries, table structures, and indexes, and was finally able to come up with a super-efficient query. However, this is still a theory question, and there are cases where the scenario I portray *does* happen (e.g. geospatial processing), subqueries that require distinct, or anything where table with definitions are joined to data.

Comment: @IanC, notice how i said "Question", instead of saying "change" ;)

Comment: @DForck42 I did see that :-) What I meant was that sometimes it is a good idea to bake in a distinct from the get-go. Not often, though.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a query like this?

You can see in the plan that SQL Server does the computation on the small number of rows pre join rather than the large number post join.

```
CREATE TABLE #BigTable
(
n INT PRIMARY KEY
);


WITH E00(N) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),   --2
        E02(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E00 a, E00 b), --4
        E04(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E02 a, E02 b), --16
        E08(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E04 a, E04 b), --256
        E16(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E08 a, E08 b)  --65,536
INSERT INTO #BigTable
SELECT TOP 10000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
FROM E16        


CREATE TABLE #SmallTable
(
n INT PRIMARY KEY
);

insert into #SmallTable select top 20 * from #BigTable ORDER BY n

SELECT SIN(COS(LOG(#SmallTable.n))) 
FROM #SmallTable join #BigTable on #BigTable.n > #SmallTable.n
```

[image: Plan]

Comment: Point once again nicely made @Martin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure of the question, to be honest...

There is no difference between a CTE and a derived table. The CTE is just a macro.

```
WITH 
  t1 AS (SELECT DISTINCT... [or GROUP BY]),
  t2 AS (SELECT DISTINCT...)
SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON ...
```

is the same as

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT... [or GROUP BY]) t1
   JOIN
   (SELECT DISTINCT...) t2 ON ...
```

Where you can have issues is associativity of tables

```
FROM
  t1
  LEFT JOIN
  t2 ON t1. = t2.
  JOIN
  t3 ON t2. = t3.
```

can be different to

```
FROM
  t1
  LEFT JOIN
  (
  SELECT *
  FROM
     t2
    JOIN
     t3 ON t2. = t3.
  ) Td ON t1. = Td.
```

However, if you need DISTINCTs in line, then it could be "why are you using EXISTS" or "why do you ave cartesian joins"

Comment: @gbn I was hoping you'd drop by. Happy New Year to you. I'm not asking about a CTE. I'm asking about if grouping/making distinct the results along-the-way has advantages in a multi-stage query, or if it is meaningless to allow the data set to keep multiplying until the very end, at which point a distinct is unoptional.

Comment: I would do it early if it makes sense. But for readability, to be honest. You may reduce intermediate results, as well as effectively breaking the problem down into steps. Subject to my final line about EXISTS or cartesian joins. Note the SQL is declarative and you're telling the optimiser only what you want, not how to do it. It may ignore any intermediate groupings, or it may "spool" results as Martin's answer shows

Comment: @gbn, does sql server "reuse" the intermediate result if you reference the same query twice in the main query? Oracle (sometimes) does it so I got curious.

Comment: @Ronnis - It can materialise the results of a CTE into a spool as here http://explainextended.com/2009/05/28/generating-xml-in-subqueries/ but doesn't usually.

Comment: I'm not calling a multi-part table function. I guess I'll have to experiment a bit and see what works best.

Comment: After some experimentation, I found it can speed things up to put strategically placed DISTINCTs. On a particular example, this reduced the base recordset from 4 to 3 records, which shaves 1s off the overall time. However, it's a different scenario to what I'm asking.